# How do you obtain Incandescent weapons from Arch-tempered Kulve Taroth?

Tags: monster-hunter-world

With the release of Arch-tempered Kulve Taroth, a new type of appraisal item has been added to the possible Siege rewards. These items, called Incandescent weapons, have a very high chance to be appraised into regular Rare 8 Kulve Taroth weapons, as well as new, more powerful Rare 8 weapons added with Arch-tempered Kulve Taroth.

The announcement video for Arch-tempered Kulve Taroth mentioned that inciting Kulve Taroth's fury and triggering her new phase during area 4 may be a requirement for receiving these weapons, as well as an all-new "Rainbow" reward slot rarity. It seemed, however, possible to receive Incandescent weapons from gold reward slots as well.

How do all these mechanics tie together? Is Kulve Taroth's fury required in order to obtain Incandescent weapons? How do you maximize the amount of Incandescent weapons obtained from the completion of a Siege?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Incandescent weapons can be rarely received from gold reward slots, and are guaranteed to appear in rainbow reward slots.

It is possible to unlock up to 8 rainbow reward slots per siege:

- Up to 2 slots are unlocked by reaching a high enough pursuit level.
- 2 slots are unlocked by starting and ending the Siege without failing or leaving a quest. Letting Kulve Taroth escape does not count as a failed quest, but triple carting does. The game refers to this as a "Single run siege".
- 2 or 4 slots (randomly chosen) are unlocked by severing Kulve Taroth's horns after inciting her fury. This is accomplished by breaking a total of 15 parts of Kulve Taroth's gold mantle before causing her to release. After breaking enough parts, the Admiral will tell the players that they have enough gold for their research, and to go ahead and break the horns.